# Postgres select max id only if value of another column is negative

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i need to write a query that will return some values but only if the latest record in that table for any user is less than 0. Here is what if been playing around with:

```
select 
    et.id,
    et.user_id,
    et.amount,
    et.trans_type,
    COALESCE(et."endingBalance", 0) AS current_balance,
    et."processId",
    upu.email,
    et.created_at
from "users-permissions_user" upu
join employer_transactions et 
    on upu.id = et.user_id 
    and et.id = (
        select max(et2.id) from employer_transactions et2 where et2."endingBalance" < 0
    )
```

and this is what is is returning:

| id | user_id | amount | trans_type | current_balance | email | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1946 | 333 | 150 | CREDIT | -900.31 | ... | ... |

but if i run this query to test that query for that user_id:

```
select 
    id, 
    user_id,
    amount , 
    trans_type, 
    "endingBalance"
from employer_transactions et 
where user_id = 333 
order by id desc;
```

here is what i see:

| id | user_id | amount | trans_type | ending_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1952 | 333 | 3 | DEBIT | 1297.31 |
| 1951 | 333 | 1 | DEBIT | 1299.31 |
| 1950 | 333 | 2 | DEBIT | 1298.31 |
| 1947 | 333 | 400 | CREDIT | 1300.31 |
| 1946 | 333 | 150 | CREDIT | -900.31 |

so in this case what im looking for was for this query to have returned nothing because the record with the highest id is not negative

but lets say the sample data set is this:

| id | user_id | amount | trans_type | ending_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 333 | 3 | DEBIT | -1297.31 |
| 899 | 333 | 1 | DEBIT | 1299.31 |
| 700 | 222 | 2 | DEBIT | -1298.31 |
| 699 | 222 | 400 | CREDIT | 1300.31 |
| 600 | 111 | 150 | CREDIT | 900.31 |
| 599 | 111 | 150 | CREDIT | -800.31 |

then what im looking for my query to return is

| id | user_id | amount | trans_type | current_balance | email | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 333 | 3 | DEBIT | -1297.31 | ... | ... |
| 700 | 222 | 2 | DEBIT | -1298.31 | ... | ... |

because those were the latest records for that particular `user_id` and the current_balance was negative but noting for `user_id: 111` becasue while yes there was a negative record but it wasnt the latest record for that `user_id`

Comment: Please provide sample output and desired result.

Comment: @user14063792468 they are pictured in the links

Comment: Canonical link: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Me have a small screen. Sometimes images can be too small, or, too big. I will not spend my time deciphering those. As many others will not.

Comment: @user14063792468 I understand what your saying. I updated my post with tables, please take a look and let me know if its easier to understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
(
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) RNK 
  FROM trans_tbl
 ) T
 WHERE T.RNK = 1 AND T.ending_balance < 0;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1fonbATtEbH2dWkpnxg9p/0)

Answer (score 0):

A common technique, for me, is to do a subquery that finds a desired subset. After that, do more filtering.

```
with ids as (
  select max(id) as last_id
  from t
  group by user_id
)

select *
from t
where end_balance < 0
  and id in (select last_id from ids)
;

The above gives desired output, given that the `id`'s are unique and form an ascending sequence.
```